# Calculating Time in HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have entered this formula in SQL Studio to calculate quantity of time in HH:MM Format:

```
 REPLACE(CAST(((CAST(C.Quantity AS DECIMAL(18,2))) / 60) + (((CAST(C.Quantity AS DECIMAL(18,2)) % 60) / 100.00)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)), '.', ':')
```

(C means Cost Table from where the total quantity of time is coming.)

However, it is giving me the wrong minutes. I entered 2:40 in the software but in the SQL Studio it is giving me 3:07 as an answer.

Can somebody check any mistake in the formula?

Comment: Provide us with an actual value to test with. `'2:40'` isn't a valid decimal, so it that's the value of `quantity`, you'll get an error.

Comment: what is `data type` for the column `Quantity` here ?

Comment: What is "Quantity". My guess: a number of seconds?
And how about spreading your line of SQLcode over multiple lines to make it better readable ?

Comment: @Larnu I just entered 2h and 40m into my software from where I am extracting data from. It can be any value related to time. you can write 5 hours and 30mins as well.

Comment: @MuhammadZakaria I think it is a Float value

Comment: quantity of time can not be float. you need to convert your time `2h 40min` into seconds first, using `h*3600 + m*60 + s = seconds` then insert this value in database.

Comment: `2h40m` isn't a valid decimal either, @user19631601 . If you don't know what value is in `Quantity` how can *we* hope to guess what it represents and turn it into a different one?

Comment: The software asks me to provide the quantity in Hours and Minutes. 
For example, Quantity: 2h 40m
The formula is trying to extract data from the software as decimal and show it in "HH:MM" Format.

Is there any way I can post pictures here to give you guys a better understanding?

Comment: OK, but what value is stored in *your database*? We don't "care" what you enter into the application, especially when that value in the database and the value in the application aren't the same.

Comment: If you enter 2H, It stores it as 120
If I enter 2h 30m, it stores it as 150
so I want to show the 150 as 2:30

Comment: Can you have values >= 1440?

Comment: @Larnu for testing purposes yes it can be added into the software. you can write 24h in it however as the software is for engineers, dont think they will work for 24 hrs straight

Answer (score 1):

As you can't have a value equal to or over 1440, then use use `DATEADD`, rather than all that fuzzy logic:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, C.Quantity, CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00'))
FROM dbo.YourTable C;
```

Comment: Any way to remove seconds.
Just tested it on SQL Studio. Shows the right answer but as "02:40:00". "02:40" would suffice

Comment: That's something for your presentation layer, in my opinion, @AK007 .

Comment: Actually that is the requirement of the person I am making the report for. The formula that I used was giving me in "H:MM" Format.

Comment: So, in the report, control the presented value, and set it to be `h:mm`, @AK007 . `h:mm` is a terrible format to pass from your SQL layer; `2:53` is *not* a larger value than `12:42`. but `'2:53'` *is* larger than `'12:42'`.

Comment: I could not understand it. Can you explain again?

Comment: In the report, define the format there. Formatting is a job for the presentation layer, *not* the SQL layer.